# DIV width:100% and text-align: center dows not work in IE 7 - need IE 7 CSS hack

Tags: css, html

i have a footer DIV

```
<div id=footer">
```

inside

```
<div id="wrapper">
```

i have set the `width: 100%` and the `text-align:center` to the `footer`... its working fine for chrome, IE 9, 8 and Firefox.

But in IE 7 its not working and i am forced to use the `margin` to align it properly.

please help.

---

### // THIS IS FOR CHROME, IE 9 , IE 8 , FF

```
    #footer .footertc {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 35px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background: #F1F1EF;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 10px;
    clear: both;
 }

#wrapper {
background: white;
background-position: 50% 0px;
width: 984px;
margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

---

### // THIS IS FOR IE 7  --> and i am forced to use margin-left

```
*+html #footer .footertc { 
           text-align:center;    -> this does not work
           margin:50px 0px 0px 550px; 
           display:block; 
           width:100%;    --> this does not work 
           height:75px; 
           background:#F1F1EF;
        }
```

Comment: Try setting a fixed with on your footer (984px maybe?) and see if that helps the text-align get settled in.

Comment: the css3 tag is wrong in this question

Comment: if i do the fixed width then it works but when scrolling it occupies the same set of pixels and i dont want that..

Answer (score 0):

You can try reset.css for minimize cross browser css problems.
More details you can see [here.](http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/yahoo-css-reset-yui-3/)